# AngularJS pass id to ng-bind-html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So I have this code:
**HTML:**

```
<span ng-bind-html="generateNavBar(navBar.common, navBar.common[0])"></span>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function ($scope){
    $scope.navBar = {
        common: [
            ["Home", "index.html"],
            ["Webpage", "index.html"],
            ["Resources", "index.html"],
            ["Login", "index.html"],
            ["Who we are", "index.html"]
        ]
    }
    $scope.generateNavBar = function (items, current){
        var navigator = '<nav><ul><b>';
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == current)
            {
                navigator += '<a href="' + items[i][1] + '"><li id="current">' + items[i][0] + '</li></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                navigator += '<a href="' + items[i][1] + '"><li>' + items[i][0] + '</li></a>';
            }
        }

        navigator += '</b></ul></nav>';

        return navigator;
    }
}]);
```

The function `generateNavBar(items, current)` is used to generate the navigation bar of each page. The function works by generating html and then returning it back. It works fine but, the issue is that it apparently cannot pass `id="current"` with the html so I tried passing in `style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000"` but that didn't work either. I know it is not a problem with the generation because when I `console.log(navigator)` it returns the HTML with the id in it. Have I done anything wrong or is it just a limitation of AngularJS? If so, is there a different method I could use?

Comment: Are you getting some error related to $sce

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. You have `ngRepeat`, `ngSrc` and other build in angularjs directives for this!

Answer (score 1):

As specified by the  Alon Eitan  you are probably missing the correct way with which you should use the angular js directives but still as for your code you have to first add trustAshtml to when you are return the string

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$sce", function ($scope,$sce){
    $scope.navBar = {
        common: [
            ["Home", "index.html"],
            ["Webpage", "index.html"],
            ["Resources", "index.html"],
            ["Login", "index.html"],
            ["Who we are", "index.html"]
        ]
    }
    $scope.generateNavBar = function (items, current){
        var navigator = '<nav><ul><b>';
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == current)
            {
                navigator += '<a href="' + items[i][1] + '"><li id="current">' + items[i][0] + '</li></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                navigator += '<a href="' + items[i][1] + '"><li>' + items[i][0] + '</li></a>';
            }
        }

        navigator += '</b></ul></nav>';

        return  $sce.trustAsHtml(navigator);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.2.29/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">

<span ng-bind-html="generateNavBar(navBar.common, navBar.common[0])"></span>
```

one more thing to remember make sure that your angular js version and angular-sanitize version are the same.